# how to get rows of table that is checked. with pagination

Tags: jquery, foreach, pagination

Theres a little bug on my code and hopping that you could help me. i have a table called contacts-employee which contains employee information and it has a checkbox on the first column. i was able to get the checked rows on the first page, but when i click next page and checked some rows, when i clicked the send button. it doesn't find any checked rows even i checked some rows..

```
to be more specific. 


var contactEmployeesPageNo = 0;

//this is the code for send
$('button[id=btn-save-emp]').click(function(){
      let employees = new Array();
      let tableControl = $('table[id=contacts-employees]');
      let sendtoctr = 0;

      $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
        let index = $(this).closest('tr').find('span[name=tbl-ctr]').text();
        if(index != ""){
          alert(index );
        }
      }).get();
    }
  });

// this is the button for pagination left
$('#contacts-employees-page-left').click(function(){
   if (contactEmployeesPageNo > 0){
     contactEmployeesPageNo = contactEmployeesPageNo - 10;
     GetContacts(contactEmployeesPageNo)
   }
});

// this is the button for pagination right
$('#contacts-employees-page-right').click(function(){
  var rowCount = $('#contacts-employees tr').length;
  if(rowCount > 1){
    contactEmployeesPageNo =  contactEmployeesPageNo + 10;
    GetContacts(contactEmployeesPageNo);
  }
});


//getting contact from php.
GetContacts = (emppage) => {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json", 
  url: 'getcontact.php',
  data: {mode:27,emppage:emppage},
  success: function(result){
      $('tbody[id=contacts-employees-list]').empty();
      $('tbody[id=contacts-employees-list]').append(result[1]);
      contactEmployees = result;
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

   },
});

//php code
 public function GetContacts($offsetemployee,$offsetsection,$offsetdepartment){

 $stmt3 = $this->db->prepare('SELECT empno, empname, concat(department," - ", position) as `position` from employees ORDER by empname ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET :page ');

 $stmt3->bindParam(':page', $offsetemployee, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt3->execute();

 $result3 = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $contacts = array();
 $html3 = '';


 if($stmt3->rowCount() > 0){
    $ctr = 0;
    $listofemployee = array();
    foreach($result3 as $row) {
       $empno = $row['empno'];
       $listofemployee[$ctr] = $empno;
       $empname = $row['empname'];
       $position = $row['position'];
       $empctr = $ctr  + 1;


       $html3 .= '<tr>
                        <td>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="emp'.$ctr.'">
                              <label class="custom-control-label" for="emp'.$ctr.'">'. $empctr .'</label>
                              <span style="display: none;" name="tbl-ctr">'. $ctr .'</span>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>'. $empname .'</td>
                        <td>'. $position .'</td>
                      </tr>';
            $ctr++;
          }
          $contacts[0] = $html3
        }else{
          $contacts[0] = "";
        }

        echo json_encode($contacts);
}

when i did not click the button for next or back page, the for loop shows the checked rows but when i click the next page or the back page, it doesnt show any checked rows even if i checked everthing on the row
```

Comment: i also tried putting the button events inside the success function of the ajax on the get contacts, but still getting the same bugs..

Comment: my point here is to make alert of the indexes which is checked input boxes on the foreach loop on button save employee. it works when i did not clicked the pagination button yet but when i clicked the pagination and clicked the save employee. nothings being alert even if i check some inputboc

Comment: This line looks like error $contacts[0] = $$html3 also may be tag this with php, ajax, jquery. And looks like some html code is missing or incomplete for table declaration.

Comment: no it is correct. it is just a typo on this post. btw the table declaraction is done on the html side and the php just ssend each rows.

Comment: The parameters you pass into php function are in wrong order, you passing 27 instead of next/prev page number for the offset, so there is nothing on page 27.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I tried this bbut doesnt work  

  GetContacts = (emppage) => {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json", 
      url: 'getcontact.php',
      data: {mode:27,emppage:emppage},
      success: function(result){
          $('tbody[id=contacts-employees-list]').empty();
          $('tbody[id=contacts-employees-list]').append(result[1]);
          contactEmployees = result;
          //this is the code for send
    $('button[id=btn-save-emp]').click(function(){
          let employees = new Array();
          let tableControl = $('table[id=contacts-employees]');
          let sendtoctr = 0;

          $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
            let index = $(this).closest('tr').find('span[name=tbl-ctr]').text();
            if(index != ""){
              alert(index );
            }
          }).get();
        }
      });`enter code here`
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

       },
    });
```